# Pinia - How to mock a specific action to test a store

Tags: pinia

Using [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html), I am not able to test what seems to be a simple scenario.

##### Store

```
const useStore = defineStore('store', () => {
  const id = ref('id');
  const forceId = ref('forceId');

  function shouldReturnForceId() {
    return false;
  }

  function getId() {
    if (shouldReturnForceId()) {
      return forceId.value;
    }
    return id.value;
  }

  return {
    id,
    forceId,
    shouldReturnForceId,
    getId,
  };
});
```

##### Helper

```
const createTestStore = (stubActions: boolean) => {
  const pinia = createTestingPinia({
    stubActions,
  });
  setActivePinia(pinia);

  const store = useStore();

  return store;
};
```

##### Test

```
describe('Pinia Test', () => {
  describe('getId', () => {
    // DOES NOT WORK - stubAction to false and mocking shouldReturnForceId
    it('should return forceId if shouldReturnForceId is true', () => {
        const store = createTestStore(false);
        store.shouldReturnForceId = jest.fn(() => true);
        expect(store.getId()).toEqual('forceId');
    });
    
    // DOES NOT WORK - stubAction to true and mocking shouldReturnForceId
    it('should return forceId if shouldReturnForceId is true', () => {
      const store = createTestStore(true);
      store.shouldReturnForceId = jest.fn(() => true);
      expect(store.getId()).toEqual('forceId');
    });
    
    // WORKS
    it('should return id if shouldReturnForceId is false', () => {
      const store = createTestStore(false);
      expect(store.getId()).toEqual('id');
    });
  });
});
```

#### Question

How is it possible to test a store by only mocking one action among several?
Reading the documentation I get that we can `stubActions: true`, which will mock all actions, but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue recently as well. There are two issues I see. One is that you are not passing the Pinia instance to the `useStore()` function. The other issue is that you should be using the `mockImplemetation()` or `vi.mocked()` function instead of assigning the value.

Try this configuration:

**Helper**

```
const createTestStore = (stubActions: boolean) => {
  const pinia = createTestingPinia({
    stubActions,
  });
  setActivePinia(pinia);
  
  // Notice that I am passing the Pinia instance to useStore
  const store = useStore(pinia);

  return store;
};
```

**Test**

```
describe('Pinia Test', () => {
  describe('getId', () => {
    it('should return forceId if shouldReturnForceId is true', () => {
      const store = createTestStore(true);
      // Notice mockImplementation fn call instead of reassignment
      store.shouldReturnForceId.mockImplementation(() => true);
      expect(store.getId()).toEqual('forceId');
    });
  });
});
```